# Android get short name of local date type

Tags: android, time, format, locale, short

I would like to display the left millis of a countdown timer in this format: `"13d, 11h:12m:14s"`. I can calculate the `times/days`, but I need the short letter of each type of the `data/time` by default Locale language of the device.

Example:

```
English: day -> d, etc 
German: tage -> t, etc, 
Hungarian: nap -> n, etc
```

I would not like to make these letters static if there is any solution to do the above format with a class.
Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checked the [source](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/) and the platform itself does not have pre-translated strings for abbreviated days, hours and so on.

Your safest option is to provide the correct abbreviations in [localized](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html) [string resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html) of your own in all languages your app supports.